# Why couldn't I edit question 79622?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I had wanted to edit [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79622/is-there-any-way-to-have-the-old-appearance-app-from-10-10-back-and-use-it-wit) to remove the signature in accordance with [this policy](https://askubuntu.com/faq#signatures) (which has since been [taken care of](https://askubuntu.com/posts/79622/revisions) by [zpletan](https://askubuntu.com/users/8724/zpletan)). However, I was unable to do so. Since I only have [1,269 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan?tab=reputation), I understand that [my edits must be approved](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit) before being visible to other users. That's not the problem. (After all, [zpletan](https://askubuntu.com/users/8724/zpletan) has only [761 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/users/8724/zpletan).) The problem was that I could not edit it at all--there was no edit link. And I have edited other people's posts before (subject to approval before being viewable)...

Now that zpletan's has edited the post and I have reloaded the page, I have an edit link. But reloading the page before that did not give me one. (I am using Chromium 15.0.874.106 (Developer Build 107270 Linux), provided by `15.0.874.106~r107270-0ubuntu0.11.10.1`, on Lubuntu 11.10.)

Was the reason I could not edit because [zpletan](https://askubuntu.com/users/8724/zpletan) had already submitted his/her edit, which was pending approval? If so, then wouldn't it be better to say something like "an edit is already pending" rather than simply not to show the edit link at all? Would the current behavior be considered a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there was already a pending edit the edit button is hidden for those who can not accept suggested edits. As you've witnessed, now that it's accepted you can once again submit your edit.

Comment: Is there a (meta)reason why the reason I couldn't edit the question wasn't made clear on the page itself? (I'm not asking specifically to that particular question, but generally for questions that cannot be edited because they have pending edits already.)

Comment: No edit button means no editing typically :) Other than that there really isn't a visible reason as to why you can't edit. With more reputation you'll see: `edit(n)` where n is the number of pending edits, typically always 1.

Comment: "*Other than that there really isn't a visible reason as to why you can't edit.*"   Which is to say that there isn't a visible reason at all (since the absence of an edit button just indicates I can't edit, not why). Anyway, I'll accept this answer, with the addition of your recent comment...but I feel that this reason for not being able to edit is extremely non-obvious.

Comment: I agree with Eliah...to anyone who doesn't know about this (including myself up until now), a missing Edit link looks an awful lot like a bug with the site.