# Why wasn't I reminded to consider accepting the answer to my question that I upvoted?

Tags: support, voting, meta, accepted-answer

I upvoted [Marco Ceppi](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/41/marco-ceppi)'s [answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2057/why-couldnt-i-edit-question-79622/2058#2058) to [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2057/why-couldnt-i-edit-question-79622/2058#2058) of mine here on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/). But I am waiting on accepting the answer until it provides more of the information I had requested. I had posted a comment to this answer, indicating that I was hoping for that information.

When I upvoted the answer, I did not see a box pop up to remind me that I could accept the answer, like I had seen when upvoting an answer to a previous question. I think I've seen that reminder box here on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/), but perhaps it was just on [main](https://askubuntu.com/).

Why didn't I see that reminder that I could accept the answer? Was it because it was on meta (reflecting the [different way votes are often used on meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/faq#vote-differences))? Or because I had just previously commented on the answer? Or because I have been using Ask Ubuntu long enough (or have accumulated enough reputation) that I am expected to know how to use the system, such that I don't need such a reminder? Or for some other reason? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's a rep limit (around 1000)

[Remind new users to choose some answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers/69777#69777)

Although in an older answer apparently it was a time limit

[Can we have an option to disable the "don't forget to accept" reminder?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-dont-forget-to-accept-reminder/14599#14599)

Probably a combination of both, or something a little more complex. In any event, I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: Does anybody know, for sure, which it is now (or what combination of the two)?